# How to log into firebase anonymously from Service or JobIntentService

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, android-service

I'm trying to log in in Firebase from these type of services in Android.

I'm able to successfully login anonymously from my main activity this way:

```
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

(more code)

mAuth.signInAnonymously().addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<AuthResult>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onSuccess(@NonNull AuthResult authResult) {

(more code to execute when the user has logged)
```

But if I try to use the same thing from a Service or JobIntentService it's impossible to do, as the first parameter for addOnSuccessListener needs to refer to an activity.

I tried to do a cast in the service to Activity to that "this", but, as expected, it didn't work.

I also tried with:

```
mAuth.signInAnonymously().addOnCompleteListener(
```

But the same happens with the first parameter, it needs to be an activity.

Under some circumstances, the mentioned services might run when the main activity is active, but not as a general rule, so I'd need something to allow a service to log in regardless of another circumstance.

Unless this was a restriction for firebase and cannot be done, which I would find pretty strange.

Answer (score 0):

I finally realized a solution:

This code:

```
while (true){
            try {
                if (mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid() == null) {

                } else {
                    break;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

            }
        }
```

Allows to wait until the user has successfully logged in into firebase.

It can be improved by limiting the number of times the loop executes, but it serves as a general idea.